# ag-grid CellRenderer component change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ag-grid-angular

I'm new to the Ag-Grid i have a field with colDef as follows

```
{
 field: XXXXXX,
 header: XXXXX,
 editabl...
 ...
 cellRenderer: (params) => {
   return '<input type= "text" ........ [readonly]="isReadonly">'
},
}
```

and i am changing the isReadonly false/true in the .ts  when click event of a button outside the aggrid.

```
private isReadonly:boolean;

...

onBtnserch(){
...
this.isReadonly = true

}
```

what im tring to archive is to make the defined input field readonly by a button click(button is out side the grid)
Am i doing it wrong or can this be done in this way if not what path should i follow.